# How to install NLTK data in windows (Anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk

I need some `NLTK` data packages in my code. I tried installing it from below command, but It installs all the packages that I do not need

```
conda install -c conda-forge nltk_data
```

How can I install specific NLTK data packages like stopwords, punkt, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing nltk using pip,run the following code in ipython

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

After this you will get a GUI where you can download all the data

If you want specific download, you can do that too. GUI looks as shown below[image]

Comment: I do not want to download all data only specific packages.

Comment: hey, you can choose from the UI

Comment: Thanks Bro for the help

Answer (score 4):

From the [NLTK documentation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html):

> Run the Python interpreter and type the commands:
>
> ```
> import nltk
> nltk.download()
> ```

A new window will pop up where you can select the packages that you wish to install.

Alternatively, you can use

```
python -m nltk.downloader <collection|package|all>
```

to install the package or collection you want, or use `all` to install all of them.

Here is a list of the packages and collections that you can use in this command, extracted from [nltk_data gh-pages](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml).

### Packages

- maxent_ne_chunker
- abc
- alpino
- biocreative_ppi
- brown
- brown_tei
- cess_cat
- cess_esp
- chat80
- city_database
- cmudict
- comparative_sentences
- comtrans
- conll2000
- conll2002
- conll2007
- crubadan
- dependency_treebank
- dolch
- europarl_raw
- floresta
- framenet_v15
- framenet_v17
- gazetteers
- genesis
- gutenberg
- ieer
- inaugural
- indian
- jeita
- kimmo
- knbc
- lin_thesaurus
- mac_morpho
- machado
- masc_tagged
- movie_reviews
- mte_teip5
- names
- nombank.1.0
- nonbreaking_prefixes
- nps_chat
- omw
- opinion_lexicon
- panlex_swadesh
- paradigms
- pe08
- pil
- pl196x
- ppattach
- problem_reports
- product_reviews_1
- product_reviews_2
- propbank
- pros_cons
- ptb
- qc
- reuters
- rte
- semcor
- senseval
- sentence_polarity
- sentiwordnet
- shakespeare
- sinica_treebank
- smultron
- state_union
- stopwords
- subjectivity
- swadesh
- switchboard
- timit
- toolbox
- treebank
- twitter_samples
- udhr
- udhr2
- unicode_samples
- universal_treebanks_v20
- verbnet
- webtext
- wordnet
- wordnet_ic
- words
- ycoe
- basque_grammars
- book_grammars
- large_grammars
- sample_grammars
- spanish_grammars
- tagsets
- mwa_ppdb
- perluniprops
- bllip_wsj_no_aux
- moses_sample
- wmt15_eval
- word2vec_sample
- vader_lexicon
- porter_test
- rslp
- snowball_data
- averaged_perceptron_tagger
- averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru
- maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
- universal_tagset
- punkt

### Collections and the packages contained within them

- all-corpora

  - abc
  - alpino
  - biocreative_ppi
  - brown
  - brown_tei
  - cess_cat
  - cess_esp
  - chat80
  - city_database
  - cmudict
  - comtrans
  - conll2000
  - conll2002
  - conll2007
  - crubadan
  - dependency_treebank
  - dolch
  - floresta
  - framenet_v15
  - framenet_v17
  - gazetteers
  - genesis
  - gutenberg
  - ieer
  - inaugural
  - indian
  - jeita
  - kimmo
  - knbc
  - lin_thesaurus
  - mac_morpho
  - machado
  - masc_tagged
  - movie_reviews
  - names
  - nombank.1.0
  - nps_chat
  - omw
  - paradigms
  - pil
  - pl196x
  - ppattach
  - problem_reports
  - propbank
  - ptb
  - qc
  - reuters
  - rte
  - semcor
  - senseval
  - sentiwordnet
  - shakespeare
  - sinica_treebank
  - state_union
  - stopwords
  - swadesh
  - switchboard
  - timit
  - toolbox
  - treebank
  - udhr
  - udhr2
  - unicode_samples
  - universal_treebanks_v20
  - verbnet
  - webtext
  - wordnet
  - wordnet_ic
  - words
  - ycoe
  - panlex_swadesh
  - mte_teip5
  - nonbreaking_prefixes
- all-nltk

  - abc
  - alpino
  - biocreative_ppi
  - brown
  - brown_tei
  - cess_cat
  - cess_esp
  - chat80
  - city_database
  - cmudict
  - comparative_sentences
  - comtrans
  - conll2000
  - conll2002
  - conll2007
  - crubadan
  - dependency_treebank
  - europarl_raw
  - floresta
  - framenet_v15
  - framenet_v17
  - gazetteers
  - genesis
  - gutenberg
  - ieer
  - inaugural
  - indian
  - jeita
  - kimmo
  - knbc
  - lin_thesaurus
  - mac_morpho
  - machado
  - masc_tagged
  - moses_sample
  - movie_reviews
  - names
  - nombank.1.0
  - nps_chat
  - omw
  - opinion_lexicon
  - paradigms
  - pil
  - pl196x
  - ppattach
  - problem_reports
  - propbank
  - ptb
  - product_reviews_1
  - product_reviews_2
  - pros_cons
  - qc
  - reuters
  - rte
  - semcor
  - senseval
  - sentiwordnet
  - sentence_polarity
  - shakespeare
  - sinica_treebank
  - smultron
  - state_union
  - stopwords
  - subjectivity
  - swadesh
  - switchboard
  - timit
  - toolbox
  - treebank
  - twitter_samples
  - udhr
  - udhr2
  - unicode_samples
  - universal_treebanks_v20
  - verbnet
  - webtext
  - wordnet
  - wordnet_ic
  - words
  - ycoe
  - rslp
  - maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
  - universal_tagset
  - maxent_ne_chunker
  - punkt
  - book_grammars
  - sample_grammars
  - spanish_grammars
  - basque_grammars
  - large_grammars
  - tagsets
  - snowball_data
  - bllip_wsj_no_aux
  - word2vec_sample
  - panlex_swadesh
  - mte_teip5
  - averaged_perceptron_tagger
  - perluniprops
  - nonbreaking_prefixes
  - vader_lexicon
  - porter_test
  - wmt15_eval
  - mwa_ppdb
- all

  - abc
  - alpino
  - biocreative_ppi
  - brown
  - brown_tei
  - cess_cat
  - cess_esp
  - chat80
  - city_database
  - cmudict
  - comparative_sentences
  - comtrans
  - conll2000
  - conll2002
  - conll2007
  - crubadan
  - dependency_treebank
  - dolch
  - europarl_raw
  - floresta
  - framenet_v15
  - framenet_v17
  - gazetteers
  - genesis
  - gutenberg
  - ieer
  - inaugural
  - indian
  - jeita
  - kimmo
  - knbc
  - lin_thesaurus
  - mac_morpho
  - machado
  - masc_tagged
  - moses_sample
  - movie_reviews
  - names
  - nombank.1.0
  - nps_chat
  - omw
  - opinion_lexicon
  - paradigms
  - pil
  - pl196x
  - ppattach
  - problem_reports
  - propbank
  - ptb
  - product_reviews_1
  - product_reviews_2
  - pros_cons
  - qc
  - reuters
  - rte
  - semcor
  - senseval
  - sentiwordnet
  - sentence_polarity
  - shakespeare
  - sinica_treebank
  - smultron
  - state_union
  - stopwords
  - subjectivity
  - swadesh
  - switchboard
  - timit
  - toolbox
  - treebank
  - twitter_samples
  - udhr
  - udhr2
  - unicode_samples
  - universal_treebanks_v20
  - verbnet
  - webtext
  - wordnet
  - wordnet_ic
  - words
  - ycoe
  - rslp
  - maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
  - universal_tagset
  - maxent_ne_chunker
  - punkt
  - book_grammars
  - sample_grammars
  - spanish_grammars
  - basque_grammars
  - large_grammars
  - tagsets
  - snowball_data
  - bllip_wsj_no_aux
  - word2vec_sample
  - panlex_swadesh
  - mte_teip5
  - averaged_perceptron_tagger
  - perluniprops
  - nonbreaking_prefixes
  - vader_lexicon
  - porter_test
  - wmt15_eval
  - mwa_ppdb
- book

  - abc
  - brown
  - chat80
  - cmudict
  - conll2000
  - conll2002
  - dependency_treebank
  - genesis
  - gutenberg
  - ieer
  - inaugural
  - movie_reviews
  - nps_chat
  - names
  - ppattach
  - reuters
  - senseval
  - state_union
  - stopwords
  - swadesh
  - timit
  - treebank
  - toolbox
  - udhr
  - udhr2
  - unicode_samples
  - webtext
  - wordnet
  - wordnet_ic
  - words
  - maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
  - maxent_ne_chunker
  - universal_tagset
  - punkt
  - book_grammars
  - city_database
  - tagsets
  - panlex_swadesh
  - averaged_perceptron_tagger
- popular

  - cmudict
  - gazetteers
  - genesis
  - gutenberg
  - inaugural
  - movie_reviews
  - names
  - shakespeare
  - stopwords
  - treebank
  - twitter_samples
  - omw
  - wordnet
  - wordnet_ic
  - words
  - maxent_ne_chunker
  - punkt
  - snowball_data
  - averaged_perceptron_tagger
- tests

  - averaged_perceptron_tagger
  - porter_test
  - twitter_samples
  - wmt15_eval
  - subjectivity
  - framenet_v17
  - product_reviews_1
  - product_reviews_2
  - vader_lexicon
  - crubadan
  - mte_teip5
  - sentence_polarity
  - universal_treebanks_v20
  - panlex_swadesh
  - nonbreaking_prefixes
  - perluniprops
  - pros_cons
  - opinion_lexicon
  - comparative_sentences
- third-party

  - dolch

Comment: just wondering.. why not delete package list? that information is available in the link you gave. Its a really really long answer .. better to put it concise?

Comment: @InAFlash No. On SO, it is better to be safe than sorry. It might be that the website gets deleted and when that happens, my answer is still valid. People cannot use the link any more, but all the information is present in the post itself. If I do not include the list, and the website is deleted, then this answer becomes useless. An answer should always be standalone and not depend on outgoing links.

Comment: and if you read the question, he asked how to install specific package.. he didn't ask to list all packages available.. if some ones asks how to install python package.. we wouldn't list all packages of python right?

Comment: anyway.. i don't mind.. its upto you.. its your answer :-D